# Nifi : Nested JSON records schema validation

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I'm trying to split a JSON file containing nested records using the SplitRecord processor.

As a result, I always get a null value instead of the expected array of records:

```
{"userid":"xxx","bookmarks":null}
```

Below is sample JSON

```
{
  "userid": "Ib6gZ8ZPwRBbAL0KRSSKS",
  "bookmarks": [
    {
      "id": "10000XXXXXXW0007760",
      "creator": "player",
      "position": 42.96
    },
    {
      "id": "41ANSMARIEEW0075484",
      "creator": "player",
      "position": 51.87
    },
    {
      "id": "ALBATORCORSW0088197",
      "creator": "player",
      "position": 93.47
    },
    {
      "id": "ALIGXXXXXXXW0007944",
      "creator": "player",
      "position": 95.06
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my avro Schema:

```
{
    "namespace": "nifi",
    "name": "bookmark",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "userid", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "bookmarks", "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "bookmarks",
                "fields": [
                    { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
                    { "name": "creator", "type": "string" },
                    { "name": "position", "type": "float" }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to implement a specific groovy processor to overcome the limitations of nifi, which took me a lot of time. The management of avro schemes is limited to the simplest cases, and does not work for advanced treatments.